# Certificate Authentication to a Point to Site Vpn with Azure key vault

Tags: powershell, azure, client-certificates, azure-keyvault, azure-vpn

I Want to Create a Point-To-Site vpn from a Virtual netwerk in azure.
For the authentication I want to use certificates, the root certificate is generated in azure key vault. I don't want to authenticate with the rootCertificate.pfx but with the clientCertificate.pfx.

The requirements are

1. that I don't use an external certificate provider.
2. I use as much powershell as possible

We followed this Documentation to **Create a self-signed certificate in key vault.**

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2016/09/26/get-started-with-azure-key-vault-certificates/

After I Created a Root Certificate, it is placed within the key vault. (public part in *secrets*, private part in *keys*)

Next We copy/paste the public part(Base64) in the Virtual Network Gateway -> point-to-site Configuration -> Root Certificates

Then I used this powershell script to generate a clientCertificate from the rootCertificate that we made earlier. We export it to our Local Hard Drive.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$kvSecret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "akv-contoso-test" -Name "ContosoFirstCertificate"
$kvSecretBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($kvSecret.SecretValueText)
$rootCertificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -ArgumentList @($kvSecretBytes, $null, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$certStore = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store
$certStore.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite)
$certStore.Add($rootCertificate)
$clientCertificate = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -KeySpec Signature -Subject "CN=Point To Site VPN Client" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyLength 2048 -Signer $rootCertificate -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2")
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "mysecret" -AsPlainText -Force
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $clientCertificate -Password $securePassword -FilePath "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Certificates\Point To Site VPN Client.pfx" -ChainOption BuildChain
$certStore.Close()
```

After that we install the "Point To Site VPN Client.pfx"

The public root certificate is installed in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities. In the chain of trust of my client certificate, the Root Certificate says the following "This certificate is not valid for the selected purpose".

Now I want to connect to the vpn with the Client Certificate.

He tells that the message received was unexpected or badly formatted.

My guess is that there is a problem when we want to generate the Client Certificate out of the keyvault (script above).

[Chain of trust and Connection Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tISxI.png)

Comment: Went through MS support, and it is currently not supported.